# Execute perl script from PHP

Tags: php, perl, shell

I trying to execute perl script from php with the following code:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/perl /var/www/html/perl/test.pl 1 2";
exec($command, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

But never works it.

I tried with system, passthru, exec_shell but script doesn't works.

Can you help me?

Comment: Any errors ?
Tried running /usr/bin/perl /var/www/html/perl/test.pl 1 2 from shell ?

Comment: Is it run from console or server? If from server: does the user running the server have the privilege to run that file? If from command line: does your user have the privilege?

Comment: What is the output of your `var_dump($output)`?

Comment: 1) Runs in console server
2) Script it works from shell
3) The result of var_dump is "".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a older version of PHP? If so, you might be runing in safe mode. 
Also you could check your folder privileges

You can read more about safe mode here [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.6.14.
In php.ini I hasn't found safe_mode directive, maybe it's deprecated in this version.